# Prove that $\sqrt[n]{a}\in \mathbb{Q}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, polynomials, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

> Let $a$ and $b$ be positive rational numbers and $n\ge 2$ be an integer so that $\sqrt[n]{a} + \sqrt[n]{b} \in \mathbb{Q}$. Prove that $\sqrt[n]{a}\in \mathbb{Q}$.

We can obviously write $a=p_1/q_1, b = p_2/q_2$ for coprime positive integers $p_1,q_1$ and $p_2,q_2$.  Let $c=\sqrt[n]{a} + \sqrt[n]{b}$. It could be useful to find a common root of some polynomials, one of which is $x^n-a$. I'm not sure what other polynomials to consider (e.g. $x^n-b, (c-x)^n - b, (c-x)^n - a$). Note that both $x^n-b$ and $(c-x)^n-a$ share a common root in $\mathbb{C}$, but I'm not sure whether this root is unique. The uniqueness of the root could be useful for proving that $\sqrt[n]{b}$ is rational, which is equivalent to the problem statement.

Comment: See Boreico’s theorem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/956415/is-x1-frac1n-1-x1-frac1n-always-irrational-if-x-is-ration?rq=1). A proof is given at [art of problem solving](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1276386p6696352). See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4356377/if-n-is-a-positive-integer-a-b-and-sqrtna-sqrtnb-are-ration?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [INMO : Prove that $\sqrt[3]{a}$ and $\sqrt[3] {b}$ themselves are rational numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3775351/inmo-prove-that-sqrt3a-and-sqrt3-b-themselves-are-rational-numbe). The answer is for general $n\ge 2$, not only $n=3$.